# How to identify the exact file which throws out the warning during batch conversion of files using obabel in bash?

Tags: bash, batch-jobs

I am using obabel tool to batch convert a set of `SDF` files to `PDB` file.

```
 obabel *.sdf -opdb --gen3d -m
```

I have ~50000 files and i am getting totally of 12 warnings in total (warning mentioned below).

```
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 5
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 2 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 4 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 12
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 11
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2 13
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 5 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 8 9 30 31 52
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
```

**How do I identify the exact 12 files which have created this warning?**

**Edit:**

As suggested, I tried to use --errorlevel 3. But sadly, that also did not help to identify the exact ligand throwing out the error. I am pasting the output got with the code. It is similar to the earlier one.

```
obabel *.sdf -opdb --gen3d --errorlevel 3 -m
```

```
obabel *.sdf -opdb --gen3d --errorlevel 3 -m
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 5
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 2 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 4 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 12
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
```

Comment: You could run `for i in *.sdf; do echo "$i"; obabel "$i" -opdb --gen3d -m; done` instead

Comment: @nohillside OK Sure. Will try and let you know

Comment: Maybe try `---errorlevel 3` or similar (the [online manual](https://openbabel.org/docs/dev/Command-line_tools/babel.html) says "---errorlevel <N>
Filter the level of errors and warnings displayed:
    1 = critical errors only
    2 = include warnings too (default)
    3 = include informational messages too"

Comment: @muru I have started a process with `error level 3` with the following code `obabel *.sdf -opdb --gen3d --errorlevel 3 -m` . Going on. I think it is going to be bit slow. Will update on completion

Comment: @muru updated the post based on result

Answer (score 1):

I don‘t know the software but if there are no interdependencies between the files you can run

```
for i in *.sdf; do
    echo "$i"
    obabel "$i" -opdb --gen3d
done
```

Comment: I tried these lines of code. The process is going on. On preliminary experience what I am finding was 

the process is bit slow and secondly as it is giving lines for all files, it is better to capture it in a txt file  using `>>` and then grep the output and see to identify the exact file. The current code is chucking out the STDOUT in terminal which becomes difficult to evaluate.

Comment: You will have to remove `-m` from the code. `-m` stands for batch conversion (that is taking individual files). Since we are using a `for` loop that is not required @nohillside

Comment: `for i in *.sdf; do
    echo "$i"
    obabel "$i" -opdb --gen3d
done`